# Maintaining records for a has_many :through from the related model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I added a Category model that uses a Categorization model for the relationships it has with a Post model. When I'm adding a new page, I would also like the user to create a category if it's not already there. Since I do not want to interrupt the workflow, it would be best to allow basic C(R)UD operations through the posts/new method.

The delete is kind of easy, since this could be a link with a method :delete to the correct route (probably through ajax).

The update and create are a bit tougher and I thought about it for a while, but couldn't come up with a solid solution.

Some of my issues:

- This would require a nested form, how does rails react to a input field that is not part of the update and besides that, HTML does not allow for nesting of forms
- If I do this through Javascript / Ajax (simple input field and a button to create/edit), how can I update the checkboxes I'm now showing for the categories.
- I'm also planning to be able to re-arrange the categories through drag&drop, but didn't even start thinking on how to fix this. Any tips on this?

I'm using this to show my checkboxes right now:

```
      # posts/new.html.haml
      .checkboxes#checkbox-list
        = f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |b|
          = b.label do
            = b.check_box
            = b.text
```

So whats SO's advise, fix this in the new Post screen or move this to a separate management page for the categories?

Comment: It really depends on what the desired user interaction is. If adding/removing categories on the fly while a post is being created than the most likely solution is using AJAX calls to separate controller. Otherwise rails has a mechanism for handling relations models in a form with [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) combined with [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/fields_for). This works perfectly well for synchronous interactions. But can lead to godlike controllers.

Comment: So how do I make these kind of decisions as a 'new to Rails' semi-amateur programmer? Is there some kind of manifest that tells you the do's and don'ts of using ruby on rails? I feel like I'm often struggling determining what to do in rails, what to do in jquery, what to handle in controllers and what to handle in models. Thanks!

Comment: There is no golden rule here. It all depends on your requirements. If you need a solution which degrades gracefully without JS use nested attributes. Otherwise I would just create an API and do the brunt of the work with jquery.